# Print $PATH from groovy - characters getting escaped?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, groovy

Bit of trouble here. I am attempting to run a snippet such as:

```
println 'echo $PATH'.execute().getText()
```

And I expect to get the contents of the system $PATH variable back. However, I instead get:

```
$PATH
```

My guess was that the $ is being escaped, and therefor not evaluated by bash. I also tried command builder syntax, same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: FYI, MacOS X 10.6 :D All set now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with Java's `Runtime.exec()`, you'll need to instantiate a shell in order that this shell variable `PATH` is visible to the process...

This should work:

```
['sh', '-c', 'echo $PATH' ].execute().text
```

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking to get the PATH, a simpler, more portable way to get it is with `System.getenv()`.  For example:

```
println System.getenv('PATH')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I didn't actually need the $PATH, that was simply my example, but your information will be useful! Thanks!